# Understanding a standard phrasing for a definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The phrase is something along the lines of

> ... the numerator of the given limit reaches zero faster than the denominator...

I think it's standard because I saw it in a few places.

For example:  [image]

---

But I am not sure I understand it. Please, see if they mean something similar to what I wrote down below. Thanks.

---

$$\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x) - [f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)]}{x - x_0} = 0 \\ \iff \frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}}(f(x) - h(x))}{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}}(x - x_0)} = 0 \\ \iff \lim_{h \to 0}\frac 0h = 0$$

The equality $\frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}}(f(x) - h(x))}{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}}(x - x_0)} = 0$ holds only if $\frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}}(f(x) - h(x))}{\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}}(x - x_0)} = \displaystyle{\frac{0}{c_i}}  = 0$ where $c_i$ is some constant. Hence we have $\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac 0h = 0}.$ According to the last limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}(f(x) - h(x)) = 0}$ which means $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta, \ |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - h(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: What is $h(x)$?

Comment: @MattE.   $h(x)$ is just a notation, shorthand for $f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$. I'll edit my OP to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct to say that $$\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)} = 0 \iff \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = c$$ which is what you seem to be implying.  It is very possible that all the limits involved are zero, namely
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0.$$  For example, if we look at $f(x) = x^2$ and consider the tangent line at $x = 1$, then we can find the tangent line $h(x) = 2x - 1$.  We have then:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x) - h(x)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 0}(x-1) = 0.$$

However, we also have $$\lim_{x\to 1}(f(x) - h(x)) = \lim_{x\to 1}(x^2 - 2x + 1) = 0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 1}(x-1) = 0.$$

What's really happening here is that once $x$ is close enough to $1$, we have that $x^2 - 2x + 1$ is always going to be closer to zero than $x - 1$ is as $x\to 1$.  That is, $x^2 - 2x + 1$ is approaching zero *faster* than $x - 1$ as $x\to 1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to x_0}\left(\frac{f(x) - h(x)}{x - x_0}\right) = 0 \\ \iff \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta, \  |x - x_0| < \delta \implies \left|\frac{f(x) - h(x)}{x - x_0}\right| < \epsilon \\ \iff x \approx x_0 \implies \left|\frac{f(x) - h(x)}{x - x_0}\right| = 0 \\ \iff x \approx x_0 \implies |f(x) - h(x)| = 0, \ |x - x_0| = \text{ constant. Is it in this sense that top reaches $0$ faster?}}$.